# Finding a previously indexed face in Rekognition using a video

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition, facial-identification

I am building a facial recognition feature for an application. I am trying to use AWS Rekognition, but apparently, it only analyzes videos through Face Liveness, which requires Amplify. I would like to know if it's possible to search for the indexed faces there by uploading a video, instead of integrating with Amplify. It would be something like identifying a face in the video and searching for the same in the already indexed faces.